# 現在の時刻のみを取得したい

Tags: swift, ios

お世話になっております。
森と申します。
質問させてください。

やりたいことは、現在の時刻のみを取得したい（日付情報はいらない）のですが、
以下のコードを書いてみたところ、

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone  = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.locale  = Locale.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let now = dateFormatter.date(from: Date().description)
```

nowがnilになってしまいます。
Date().descriptionは、
「2020-03-23 02:13:50 +0000」
となっております。

どなたかわかる方、
ご教授をお願い出来ますでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

最後の行を

```
let now: String = dataforatter.date(from: Date())
```

とすれば動きます。

もしくは、`.date(from string: String)`をどうしても使いたいのであれば、

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone  = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.locale  = Locale.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ" // パースのためのフォーマット
let dateForTime: Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: Date().description)
if let date: Date = dateForTime {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"             // 出力のためのフォーマット
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
}
```

と、日付文字列をパースする時と、出力するときでプロパティ`dateFormat`を随時必要な形式に更新してあげれば`Date().description`からでも時刻部分だけが取り出せます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
要件を満たすことが出来ました。

Comment: `DateFormatter`を`"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"`のような固定フォーマットで使用する場合には、`locale`を`Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`で指定しなければいけません。([Working With Fixed Format Date Representations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter#2528261))